# Unable to generate Facelets error page as the response has already been committed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor

I'm writing jsf web application. I use primefaces and glassfish in netbeans.

I want to use CKEditor but I get error

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

my component news.xhtml:

```
<pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{compNoticiaManutencaoMB.content}" interfaceColor="#D8D8D8" >
    <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{compNoticiaManutencaoMB.saveListener}" update="growl"/>
</pe:ckEditor>
```

error:

```
INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INPUT_TEXT_EVENTS

...

WARNING: JSF1087: Unable to generate Facelets error page as the response has already been committed.
SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: INPUT_TEXT_EVENTS
javax.faces.FacesException: INPUT_TEXT_EVENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because org.primefaces.util.HTML doesn't contain INPUT_TEXT_EVENTS. The solution is update to Primefaces 5 or downgrade PrimeFaces Ext to version 1.2.1